# Why I can start CIDER's Clojure REPL without a project (no error message) but starting CIDER's clojureScript REPL without a project returns an error?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, cider, shadow-cljs

I have been using with some success the stack of Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, Emacs, and CIDER.

Usually, **inside a project** and for ClojureScript projects, I do: `cider-jack-in-cljs`, I choose `shadow-cljs`, then `shadow` for REPL type, and `app` for build option.

It works (mostly). Now, I tried the same approach but **without a project**.

Instead of normally working, I received the following error message:

> error in process filter: ClojureScript is not available.  See https://docs.cider.mx/cider/basics/clojurescript for details

Still, the REPL is running, but it seems to be only Clojure, not clojureScript - I can do math but no interaction with the browser:

```
user> (+ 1 2 3)
6

user> (js/alert "test")
Syntax error compiling at (*cider-repl ~:localhost:53866(clj)*:49:7).
No such namespace: js
```

I tried reading the mentioned link. But it only gives general information. It does not seem to answer the problem in case:

Why I can't start CIDER clojureScript REPL without a project?

Obs.: If I try the same thing with `cider-jack-in-clj` (which means using Clojure and not ClojureScript) the REPL starts (as `user`) and there is **no error message**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I was trying to get emacs org babel to execute clojurescript (NOT clojure) to execute. I read the [docs](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/basics/clojurescript) and the error message and tried to add a `deps.edn` file with clojurescript as dependency:

```
{:deps {org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.11.4"}}}
```

I tried `cider-jack-in-cljs` again with `node` as repl type and it worked.

```
#+begin_src clojurescript
  (js/Date.)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: #inst "2022-10-12T08:45:52.091-00:00"
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, add the dependency in emacs directly:

```
(add-to-list 'cider-jack-in-cljs-dependencies '("org.clojure/clojurescript" "1.11.4"))
```